# Remove bulk option row

Tags: wp-admin, admin, bulk, row-actions

How can I remove bulk actions section from post and page lists pages on wordpress

[image]

I tried with following code in functions.php as suggested on another thread but it does nothing

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_53371_remove_bulk_actions' );
function wpse_53371_remove_bulk_actions()
{
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', '__return_empty_array' );
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-upload',    '__return_empty_array' );
}
```

Should I hide it will css ?

Comment: Not sure what row you want to hide here, do you e.g. have a screenshot, that could help others better understand the question?

Comment: I updated the question with screenshot

Comment: Where you've put your code ? I wanna know the file name. Like `functions.php` etc.

Comment: yes I placed it in functions.php file , tried with plugin as well.

Comment: Does not it workings every where or only in a custom post or in `post` or `page` post type ?